# unknown problem reaction detection discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm writing a command to add roles to a user by having them react to a message. here is my code:

```
@BOT.command(pass_context = True , name = "join_game")
async def join_game(context):
    roles = {"minecraft" : "minecraft" , "AC" : "animal crossing" , "pokemon" : "pokemon"} #"emoji_name" : "role_name" , ...
    roleEmojis = {get(context.message.guild.emojis, name = emoji_name) : get(context.message.guild.roles , name = role_name) for emoji_name , role_name in zip(roles , roles.keys())}
    reactions = []
    msg = await context.message.channel.send("react with which game(s) you would like to be a part of.\n**press the :OK: when you are done**")

    for emoji in roleEmojis.keys():
        await msg.add_reaction(emoji)
    await msg.add_reaction(get(context.message.guild.emojis, name = "OK"))

    while True:
        reaction , user = await BOT.wait_for("reaction_add" , check = lambda react , user : True if react in [emoji for emoji in roleEmojis.keys()] and user == BOT.user else False) 
        if reaction == get(context.message.guild.emojis, name = "OK"):
            continue
        else:
            reactions.append(reaction)

    print(reactions)

    #add roles
```

everything works as expected, there are no errors but it won't detect when I add a reaction, as in there is no output and the while loop continues on forever without breaking. I am confident it is to do with my check function, but to be honest I'm not all that sure. ill not that this is my first attempt at my first bot and I likely missed something very obvious.

Comment: any other unrelated improvements are appreciated by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using the client event `on_reaction_add`.

(I'm assuming that you already have defined `get()` elsewhere in the code)

```py
@BOT.command(pass_context = True , name = "join_game")
async def join_game(context):
    roles = {"minecraft" : "minecraft" , "AC" : "animal crossing" , "pokemon" : "pokemon"} #"emoji_name" : "role_name" , ...
    roleEmojis = {get(context.message.guild.emojis, name = emoji_name) : get(context.message.guild.roles , name = role_name) for emoji_name , role_name in zip(roles , roles.keys())}
    reactions = []
    msg = await context.message.channel.send("react with which game(s) you would like to be a part of.\n**press the :OK: when you are done**")

@BOT.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):

    # check if the user did the command #
    message = reaction.message
    if reaction.emoji == get(message.guild.emojis, name='minecraft'):
        role_to_assign = message.guild.get_role(ID_OF_MINECRAFT_ROLE_GOES_HERE)
    elif reaction.emoji == get(message.guild.emojis, name='AC'):
        role_to_assign = message.guild.get_role(ID_OF_ANIMALCROSSING_ROLE_GOES_HERE)
    elif reaction.emoji == get(message.guild.emojis, name='pokemon'):
        role_to_assign = message.guild.get_role(ID_OF_POKEMON_ROLE_GOES_HERE)
    elif reaction.emoji == get(message.guild.emojis, name='OK'):
        # do stuff to clean up (no more roles assigned) #
        return
    await user.add_role(role_to_assign)
```